# Auto-completion in PyDev

Tags: pydev

I have **PyDev 2.2.1** on Eclipse Indigo and I can't get auto-completion to work. I have checked all options in the `PyDev->Editor->Code Completion menu`, but still I get no hints.

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us an example of when you think there would be autocomplete and there is not?

Comment: For instance:

from owslib.wps import WebProcessingService
wps = WebProcessingService('http://cida.usgs.gov/climate/gdp/process/WebProcessingService', verbose=False, skip_caps=True)
wps.

Nothing shows up after "wps."